# Semilattice whose Subsets are All Closed -- does it have a special name?

Tags: terminology, order-theory, lattice-orders, semigroups

Context: self-education.

I am currently getting my head round semilattices.

My understanding is that a semilattice $(S, \odot)$ is a semigroup whose operation $\odot$ is both commutative and idempotent, that is:

- $\forall x, y \in S: x \odot y = y \odot x$
- $\forall x \in S: x \odot x = x$

One of the first things you find out is that $\odot$ induces an ordering $\preccurlyeq$ defined as:
$$x \preccurlyeq y \iff x \odot y = y$$

from which it follows after some straightforward algebra that:

$$x \odot y = \sup_\preccurlyeq \{x, y\}$$

and lo and behold, we have a **join semilattice**.

> ASIDE: There's very much a chicken-and-egg thing going on here. That is, from what I can tell from the literature, often the join semilattice is defined directly on an ordered set, from which the "join" operation is then defined as $x \vee y := \sup \{x, y\}$, rather than starting with the abstract semilattice and then creating the operation on that.

But there is an added level of interest when $(S, \odot)$ is such that **every subset of $S$ is a subsemilattice of $S$**, that is, every subset is closed under $\odot$. Because in that case, the ordering induced on $(S, \odot)$ is **total**. And conversely, the join operation defined on a set by a total ordering is such that every subset is closed under that join operation.

> ASIDE: I note that the usual symbol for the operation here is $\vee$, for "join", or $\wedge$ for "meet", and a distinction is usually made between the two, where the ordering induced by $\wedge$ is the other way round from the one induced by $\vee$, but as these things are dual, the distinction is arguably less important at the most abstract level than might otherwise be inferred. Hence my "neutral" notation $\odot$.

My question is:

Is there a special name for such a semilattice - one whose subsets are *all* subsemilattices? Or do we have to resort to cumbersome verbal constructs like "Let $(S, \odot)$ be a semilattice whose subsets are all closed under $\odot$" or "Let $(S, \odot)$ be a semilattice whose subsets are all subsemilattices"?

> EDIT: I wonder whether the world would object if I were to suggest the neologism **total semilattice**. This would neatly dovetail with the fact that the ordering it induces is a **total ordering**.

Comment: I don't think we need a name for every concept. If you want one here, choose some X = 'total', 'linear', or 'simple'. For any of these choices one might say 'X order' or 'X-ly-ordered semilattice'. But 'total semilattice' is not a good choice. The most likely interpretation of 'total semilattice' is 'a semilattice whose operation is totally defined', as opposed to a 'partial semilattice'.

Comment: @KeithKearnes "I don't think we need a name for every concept." No, but we need a name for concepts we need a name for innit.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of ordered sets, it is called a *linear order*. In terms of semigroups, I would call it a *chain of idempotents*.

Comment: It *can* be called a "linear order", but that's just suboptimal synonym for "total order", and I've already established its role in this object. And in the literature I have been able to access online referring to "chains of idempotents" seem to have nothing to do with total orderings or even semilattices.

Comment: On the first point, the book by J. Rosenstein, *Linear orderings*. Pure and Applied Mathematics, 98. Academic Press, Inc. , New York-London, 1982, is the reference book on total orders, and apparently, this author does not consider the term *linear order* as "suboptimal". For the second point, every semigroup theorist would understand what it means for a semigroup to be a *chain of idempotents*.

Comment: Okay let's not argue over terminology -- I appreciate that some people have different ideas over names of things. But for the record, "total" is better than "linear" because it makes the apposition with "partial ordering" more apparent, and besides, "linear" is overused. IMO. For the more important point, why can I not find any online definition of "chain of idempotents" to be synonymous with "semilattice whose subsets are all subsemilattices"? I feel uncomfortable with "every <whoever> would understand" for reasons which I hope are apparent.